# Find Constant Term of Polynomial with Lagrange Interpolation

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, polynomials

here's the scenario.

I've written a function, that given an array of x and y coordinates, calculates the constant term of a polynomial using Lagrange's interpolation. The function seems to work on my end, but when I submit it, the system says 'wrong answer'. I've even used a tool at [dcode.fr](https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial) to verify that my answers are correct, but still, no luck upon submission.

See the function below. All values in y should be reduced modulo p.

```
def interpolation(y_coords, x_coords):
    constant_term = 0
    p = 1000000007

    for x in x_coords:
        if x < 0 or x > 1000:
            return 0

    for y in y_coords:
        y = y % p
        if y < 0 or y > p:
            return 0

    for i in range(0, len(x_coords)):
        x = 0
        li_x = 1

        for j in range(0, len(x_coords)):
            if i != j:
                li_x = li_x * (x - x_coords[j]) / (x_coords[i] - x_coords[j])

        constant_term += li_x * y_coords[i]

    return(int(constant_term))


y_coords = [9, 19, 35]
x_coords = [1, 2, 3]

print(interpolation(y_coords, x_coords))
```

Sample input:
y_coords = [9, 19, 35]
x_coords = [1, 2, 3]

Output: 5 (an integer)

I'd love another eye on this to see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In such problems, to avoid overflow, you generally need to take the modulo after each operation

Comment: @Damien when I tried that, I got some widely incorrect answers.

Comment: How did you try exactly? You have to calculate a numerator (-Prod x_j) and a denominator (Prod(x_i - x_j, j not equal to i), both modulo P. Then, you have to calculate the inverse of the denominator modulo P (see wikipedia, [modulo multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)  )

Comment: @Damien this is what I initially did:

li_x = li_x * (x - x_coords[j] % p) / (x_coords[i] % p - x_coords[j] % p)

Comment: If you have many variables, the numerator and denominator can become higher than P, even if it is not the case for the x[i]